# pandas to_json - return timestamp with units of days rather than seconds

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas series containing datetime objects which have been created from day-month-year strings

```
series = pd.Series(['3/11/2000', '3/12/2000', '3/13/2000'])
series = pd.to_datetime(series)

print series
0   2000-03-11
1   2000-03-12
2   2000-03-13
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Later, after using these datetime objects, I want to convert this series into json in a format day-month-year. However, to_json returns the datetime with HH:MM:SS etc

```
json = series.to_json(orient='index', date_format='iso', date_unit = 's')
print json
{"0":"2000-03-11T00:00:00Z","1":"2000-03-12T00:00:00Z","2":"2000-03-13T00:00:00Z"}
```

Is there any inbuilt and elegant way to just return the dates as so

```
{"0":"2000-03-11","1":"2000-03-12","2":"2000-03-13"}
```

without the HH:MM:SS etc. The closest I have got (without converting to strings and writing a function to parse) is the date_unit argument of to_json although the largest time unit is seemingly seconds.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
In [64]: series.dt.date.astype(str).to_json()
Out[64]: '{"0":"2000-03-11","1":"2000-03-12","2":"2000-03-13"}'
```

Comment: OP may want `series.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y').to_json()` to get the dates in day-month-year format.

Comment: @unutbu That might be the case, in general, in which case an `apply` would do it. In this specific case, though, the OP posted the exact output, no?

Comment: The OP also wrote, "I want to convert this series into json in a format day-month-year." So it's a bit unclear.

Comment: @unutbu Oh, yes - I see that now. Good point, thanks. (OP: if this is the case, then `apply` is indeed your friend, but please align the example with your words in the future.)

Comment: @AmiTavory Will do

Answer (score 3):

This is not elegant but you can try convert to string before to json:

```
>>> series.apply(lambda x : x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).to_json()
'{"0":"2000-03-11","1":"2000-03-12","2":"2000-03-13"}'
```

Comment: This is a very flexible answer.

Comment: @AmiTavory: But very slow.  :)

Comment: `series.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` would be much better i think